# Proper Global Variable definition/declaration

Tags: c++, global-variables

This is probably a pretty straight forward question but for some reason I haven't been able to find an answer on the great interwebs so far.

When using global variables, I know global variables are bad and should for the most part be avoided, but on those rare occasions where a global variable gets the job done best, should the global variable be both declared and initialized at once? I have been recently trying to drill into my head the mantra "always initialize variables upon declaration when possible" since this usually saves many headaches later and is encouraged with C++. Does this rule apply to global variables as well though?

If you initialize a variable in its global scope when declaring it, how does this affect the program? Is this best practice?

You're advice is very much appreciated!

Comment: **Always initialize global variables!** (or the compiler will do that for you with standard values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to initialize variables at the point they are declared whenever possible, regardless of their scope.

For global variables, if you don't initialize them when they are declared, you need to initialize them after your program starts running, which leaves open the possibility that the global will be used before this occurs. Classes, with constructors, will be default constructed, which can cause work to be done and thrown out when the variable is assigned its proper value.

Global variables have another problem: the order they are constructed/initialized is only partially defined by the language. If you have two global variables that are declared in different source modules, you do not know which one will be constructed first. This can lead to the *static initialization order fiasco*.

So you can run into problems if you initialize them, or different problems if you don't. This is one reason why global variables should be avoided.

What is the solution? You can wrap your global variables into an accessor function. This will ensure that the variable has been properly initialized. So rather than the plain declaration:

```
SomeType big = ReadBig();
```

you can place it into a function:

```
const SomeType &GetBig() {
    static SomeType big = ReadBig();
    return big;
}
```

This also has the advantage of having your global variable `const`, so that it cannot be changed if this is necessary.

Comment: _"static initialization order fiasco"_ doesn't that only happen when those global variables are not independent from each other? (And if those global variables are not independent from each other, you have at least 1 global variable too much.) I'm also pretty sure that global variables may also be global constants. I find your approach of reinventing a global variable with the help of a function curious. I see no advantage there, but disadvantages.

Comment: @paladin If the globals are independent then it doesn't matter what order they are constructed in. The problem arises when the order does matter. The approach of having a function return a reference or pointer to a local static variable is common. One implementation of the factory pattern will do this (with a static member function of the class returning a reference to a local static variable declared within the function).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do want to initialize global variables. As @paladin commented, if you do not initialize them, the compiler will attempt to initialize them with the default values.
Consider this simple example:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int x, char *y, double z) {}
};

Foo f;
```

The compiler will try to initialize `f`, but there is no default constructor. This configures an error:

```
<source>:5:5: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Foo'
Foo f;
    ^
<source>:1:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
```

So yes, you need to initialize your global variables, and if you don't the compiler will try to do it for you.